# Change TextView Action when Button is clicked

Tags: javascript, android

In Android Studio I have made a TextView showing "dailyQuote1" when i press/tapping the TextView.

I also added a button with id "buttonquote2", when I press that button once I want that the "action" of the TextView to start showing "displayQuote2" instead of "displayQuote1" when press/tapping TextView.

How should the code for the button look like to do this?

TextView "action":

```
   TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewNextQuote);
            mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    displayQuote1(); //I want this to change
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this What you can do is implement 
     View.OnClickListener with the class or activity you are working with and then check for the id of the view which is being clicked/tapped and choose the method according to the id. Like this

```
class MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 TextView textView=findViewById....
 Button button=findViewById...

 textView.setOnClickListener(this)
 button.setOnclickListener(this)
 }

 override onClick(View view) {
 switch(view.getId())
 {

 case textView.getId():
 displayQuote1();

 case button.getId(): 
 displayQuote2();

 }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void buttonClick(View v)
{
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText(displayQuote2());
}
```